# Calculating rounded border size for inner element to match with outer element

Tags: jquery, rounded-corners, css

As you can see in this example, two nested elements with the same pixel value for rounded borders don't match up:

http://jsfiddle.net/bMFaH/

Now, is there some kind of javascript that I could run to "calculate", based on width/height/border thickness/... what the inner border-radius should be?

Reason is I would need this for a lot of different (user set) border-radiuses and element sizes, so I can't just input a static value.

Edit: OK did some further testing, is this correct:

```
Outer radius: x pixels
Outer border: y pixels
Inner radius: x-y pixels
```

Thanks in advance,
Wesley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know how to get and set css values, the "formula" to get the outer border-radius is

```
inner.border-radius + outer.border-width
```

Seems quite straight-forward to get javascript script doing the math.

EDIT:
Or, as you mentionned, you can calculate inner border-radius with outer.border-radius - outer.border-width as well.